# Where to find detailed SQL Server messages for a SQL Agent job

Tags: sql-server

Where can I find the detailed messages associated with a given SQL Agent job?

In SSMS, I looked in SQL Server Agent/ Error Logs (View Agent Log), Viewing History, Job Steps Execution History, and View Job Activity. All of these only show the high level info such as Job Step completion info.

Comment: Do you have Verbose logging enabled for your server?

Comment: @Dresden: No, "Include execution trace messages" is not flagged.

Comment: I know that's a way to see more detailed SQL Agent logs that aren't just critical/error results and can easily be toggled if you want to turn them off again later.  What kind of information are you looking for specifically about the jobs that are running?  The only reason I ask is that most of the advanced logging options for SQL jobs are setup manually and don't come enabled by default.

Comment: @Dresden: I'm looking for error messages that were thrown  (e.g. with T-SQL THROW command), and any other messages that are part of the job. Row counts returned would be nice, but are not required. SSIS does a nice job of showing what happened with a job. I'm trying to find something similar for T-SQL scripts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537355/retrieving-the-an-sql-agent-jobs-specific-error - Seems like a relevant discussion on using sp_help_jobhistory to get more detailed information about a specific job.  You can even look at all steps by step_id or using step_id=0 for a job history.